# Delete from iptables where source is X

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm running `iptables` on `Debian 8` and needs to make some dynamic adjustment of certain rules.

So I'm looking for a way to something like:

```
iptables -D WHERE -s = x.y.z
```

So I can delete all rules from `iptales` where the source ip is matching x.y.z. Instead of need to know which line in iptales it is.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your firewall is rule based and the default commandline interface can't really use pattern matching to directly delete a number of different rules.

I would use `iptables-save` as an intermediate step to get your current running configuration and do pattern matching on that, substituting the **A**dd for **D**elete commands:

```
iptables-save | grep -- '-s ip-address/prefix' | sed s/^-A/-D/ |xargs iptables
```

Comment: It seems I'm able to run ex. `iptables -D INPUT -s = x.y.z -J ACCEPT` actually, but I have to give the exact complete rule. Had hope to be able to simply do `iptables -D input -s = x.y.z` and then all rules with that source would be deleted.

Comment: I'm not to keen on iptables-save as there might be 100K+ rules and it may be called via API from users, so `iptables-save` could be run in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

HBruijn's solutions works just fine if you have to find and modify a single rule. To replace all rules with the selected IP address I would use something like this:

```
iptables-save | grep -e '-s x.x.x.x/zz' | sed 's/-A/-D/' | while read i; do iptables $i; done;
```